# Shiny Modules not working with renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

I am using renderUI to optionally present a Table or Plot based on user selection of the visualization option. I am also using Shiny modules to present the same thing on multiple tabs. While I have gotten Shiny modules to work wonderfully in another app, I am struggling to get it to work with renderUI.

Here is a minimal piece of code that I came up with that shows the problem where nothing gets displayed on either tabs:

```
myUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput(ns('myFinalText'))
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabBox(id = 'myBox', width = 12,
         tabPanel('Tab1',
                  fluidRow(
                    myUI('tab1')
                  )),
         tabPanel('Tab2',
                  fluidRow(
                    myUI('tab2')
                  ))
         )
)

myTextFunc <- function(input, output, session, text) {
  output$myFinalText <- renderUI({
    output$myText <- renderText({text})
    textOutput('myText')
  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myTextFunc, 'tab1', session = session, 'Hello Tab1')
  callModule(myTextFunc, 'tab2', session = session, 'Hello Tab2')
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any thoughts on what else I should be doing to make this work?

Replacing the Shiny module UI function and server functions as follows makes it work fine.

```
myUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    textOutput(ns('myFinalText'))
  )
}

myTextFunc <- function(input, output, session, text) {
  output$myFinalText <- renderText({
    text
  })
}
```

Comment: Having `textOutput` in the server function doesn't really make sense. As you say, the replacement works, so what is the first version supposed to be doing that isn't provided by the second? I am confused by the intent of your `myTextFunc` nested structure.

Comment: Obviously my code (UI and server functions are very complex) and doing much more than rendering simple text. I am just using this example to show that renderUI is not working with Shiny Modules - in my case as I am trying to use it. I want the renderUI to render the same 'tab1' and 'tab2' text. If this works, I can figure out my real use case.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the namespace from the session object. Change `myTextFunc` in the initial app like this:

```
myTextFunc <- function(input, output, session, text) {
    ns <- session$ns
    output$myFinalText <- renderUI({
        output$myText <- renderText({text})
        textOutput(ns('myText'))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't call output$ function from another output$ function - it's against Shiny design patterns.

```
output$myFinalText <- renderUI({
    output$myText <- renderText({text})
    textOutput(ns('myText'))
})
```

If you want to know, why it is very bad practice, watch Joe Cheng tutorial about 'Effective reactive programming' from this site: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/.

You should use rather reactiveValues or reactive expressions instead. What exactly you should use is dependent from what do you want to achieve, so it's hard to say without detailed example, but according to Joe Cheng everything can be accomplished without nesting outputs or observers.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your functions with this `renderUI` equivalent also works:

```
myUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput(ns('myFinalText'))
  )
}

myTextFunc <- function(input, output, session, text) {
  output$myFinalText <- renderUI({
    text
  })
}
```

Although this obviously does not capture the complexity of what you are really doing. There's something not right about using `output$...` and `textOutput` within the `renderUI` like that. I don't think that is necessary - you don't actually have to use the `textOutput` function to include text in your output.

EDIT: It occurs to me that the problem has to do with namespaces and modules. When you do `output$myText <- renderText(text)`, the result ends up in the namespace of `tab1` or `tab2`. For example, try changing your `textOutput` to

```
textOutput('tab1-myText')
```

and watch what happens. I think this is why having `output$..` variables in your `renderUI` is problematic. You can access *inputs* via `callModule` and that should take care of any namespace issues.

Comment: Ok, your edited response is helpful and useful. Indeed it has to do with namespaces. I guess my question is really about how to resolve it on the server side. I have to use renderUI because I am providing a 'table' or 'plot' options for visualizations, and want to dynamically switch them out.

Comment: One way of fixing it wold be to store the output of NS() into a global variable, and then pass it into the call module. Yucky, but, would/should work. Will try that.

Comment: In the server, something like `vizOptSelected <- reactive(input$vizOptSelector)`, and then `output$vizToBeShown <- renderUI({if (vizOptSelected() == 'table') {tableOutput(...)} else {plotOutput(...)} })`.

Comment: And that also could all be modularized, using `callModule` instead of `reactive(input$..)` and so forth.

Comment: I know how to do that part... :) Just the namespace inheritance is the one roadblock - minus my hack above.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect what you are looking for is `callModule` to get at values from namespaced instances. No hack should be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering my own question...but for others looking for a similar solution, this may be of help.

Here is how I solved for the need to inherit Shiny module namespace on the server side to dynamically render UI. IF there is a better way to solve, please comment or post.

```
tab1NS <- NS('tab1')
tab2NS <- NS('tab2')

myUI <- function(ns) {
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      radioButtons(ns('type'), 'Select Visual:',
                   choices = c('Table' = 'table',
                               'Plot' = 'plot'))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput(ns('myCars'))
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabBox(id = 'myBox', width = 12,
         tabPanel('Tab1',
                  fluidRow(
                    myUI(tab1NS)
                  )),
         tabPanel('Tab2',
                  fluidRow(
                    myUI(tab2NS)
                  ))
         )
)

myTextFunc <- function(input, output, session, cars, ns) {
  getMyCars <- reactive({
    if (input$type == 'table') {
      output$table <- renderDataTable({datatable(cars)})
      dataTableOutput(ns('table'))
    } else{
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plot(cars$wt, cars$mpg)
      })
      plotOutput(ns('plot'))
    }
  })
  output$myCars <- renderUI({
    getMyCars()
  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myTextFunc, 'tab1', session = session,
             mtcars[mtcars$am == 1, ], tab1NS)
  callModule(myTextFunc, 'tab2', session = session,
             mtcars[mtcars$am == 0, ], tab2NS)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```